# z-index problem when printing from Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, printing, z-index

When you print in IE it prints content in the layer below the top one.

Any way around this. I'd rather do it via css than a setting in the browser.

Many thanks, Jools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you messing with layering in the print view? You should disable layering and just show a plain text view of data, or not even render those areas on a printed page.

Again, it helps knowing what you are actually dealing with instead of being vague.

Comment: When I designed the page I didn't think about printing. I needed to hide a div behind another which I did by making its z-index negative. When I print, the div which is not visible when I view it on screen shows up. I want it to remain hidden.

Comment: I disagree with this, there's no reason why you should just show a plain text view of data for printing - CSS was designed to handle print or any screen. This is why CSS media types exist. I have used layering to create watermarks in printed pages several times. You just need to work out your positioning, transparency, etc.